# Android Bluetooth Cross-Transport Key Derivation support on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is Android officially supporting CTKD? From the [BlueZ documentation](http://www.bluez.org/page/4/):

> Another improvement that LE SC brings is what’s called cross-transport
> key derivation. What this means is that when two dual-mode (supporting
> LE + BR/EDR) devices pair with each other, they only need to pair over
> either LE or BR/EDR to get the encryption keys for both transports in
> one go.

I haven't found any information in the official Android docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no documentation about it, but it is supported, take a look to:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/heads/master/gd/security/pairing_handler_le.cc#199

I was able to trigger CTKD (BLE -> BR/EDR) connecting to GATT (BluetoothDevice::connectGatt) and when the connection state becomes STATE_CONNECTED then trigger the pairing request (BluetoothDevice::createBond). Then I got paired to BLE and CTKD generates the BR/EDR link key.

Comment: Good find, thanks! This code seems to be added in the mid 2020 in a bugfix: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/53be96744cf9fbcffe6f4d56f6f3790ce0624969%5E%21/gd/security/pairing_handler_le.cc - any idea what is the lowest Android version supporting CTKD officially?